# Is it possible to UPDATE then INSERT in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to UPDATE and then INSERT where row exists in mysql? I have this query,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET lifeforce = maxLifeforce, inHospital = 0 WHERE hospitalTime <= NOW() AND inHospital = 1");
$q -> execute();
```

How can I either get the primary key into an associative array to then do an insert for each item in the array, or do an UPDATE AND INSERT?

Or does it involve doing a SELECT to get all that match criteria, then UPDATE then INSERT using array from the select? This seems rather a long way to do it?

Basically I need to INSERT onto another table using the same primary keys that get updated.

Comment: It might be me, but I have no clue what you mean. Do you mean that you want to update excisting rows, and if they don't you want to insert? Or something else? The former might be "replace", the latter would need explanation :)

Comment: No, I need to do an insert on another table on the same rows that get updated using the primary key, if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, it might mean that your database-scheme doesn't make too much sense if there is such a relation, but that's a bit guessing and probably premature of me. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or does it involve doing a SELECT to get all that match criteria, then UPDATE then INSERT using array from the select?

Yes, sorry, that's the main way.

Another approach is to add a column called (say) `last_updated`, that you set whenever you update the column. You can then use that column in a query that drives your insert. That would have other advantages — I find `last_updated` columns to be useful for many things — but it's overkill if this is the only thing you'd ever use it for.

---

**Edited to add:** Another option, which just occurred to me, is to [add a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) to your `accounts` table, that will perform the insert you need. That's qualitatively different — it causes the insertion to be a property of `accounts`, rather than a matter of application logic — but maybe that's what you want? Even the most extreme partisans of the "put-all-constraints-in-the-database-so-application-logic-never-introduces-inconsistency" camp are usually cautious about triggers — they're really not a good way to implement application logic, because it hides that logic somewhere that no-one will think to look for it. But if the table you're inserting into is some sort of `account_history` table that will keep track of all changes to `account`, then it might be the way to go.

Comment: @cgwebprojects: You're welcome! Also, another option just occurred to me; I've edited my answer to describe it. I'm a bit hesitant to suggest it, because it's very likely a bad idea; but on the other hand, it might be exactly the *right* thing to do, depending on the semantics of your insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiple table update as written in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

If the second table needs an insert, you probably would have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysqli_last_id function:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Also, when running consecutive queries like that, I'd recommend using transactions:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/implement-mysql-based-transactions-with-a-new-set-of-php-extensions/6085922